# Increasing intensity of RGB in PIL

Tags: python, colors, python-imaging-library, rgb, imaging

I have an image which i can import into my terminal and plot into 4 different pictures, the original, one with just R, just G and just B shown. However what i want to do now is be able to increase the intensity of just 1 colour band, e.g. G*1.2 (or being able to increase it say by 100 units) and then be able to put the images back together after the last has been modified. heres what i have so far:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('RedSunset.jpg')

#from _future_ import print_function
print(im.format, im.size, im.mode)

im.show()

rgbim = im.convert('RGB')
r, g, b = rgbim.split()
#im = Image.merge("RGB", (b, g, r)) #thinking of using this to put them back

b.show()
r.show()
g.show()
```